# Hi! I'm having trouble converting this drawn graphic into a vector (illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I'm currently a UX designer doing a favor for a loved one. They have a logo, I'll attach below, but I'm having trouble with the steps to convert this drawn image into a vector in illustator.

I haven't used illustrator since college (I work mostly in Figma), so what would seem simple enough is turning out to be much harder than I thought.

Here's the logo: [image: Drawn logo version]

I thought the steps would be simple:

1. Make text into shape
2. Create heart shape and insert that between the 'l' and the 'r'
3. Create mask with holographic image (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9f4P.jpg))
4. Create a thick stroke with appropriate color
5. Bevel and Extrude to create 3D effect

I'm having trouble with even the simplest step. Is it possible someone could walk me through how to execute this in illustrator? If not, how do I even go about converting a text into a shape that can be manipulated and edited?

Comment: You want to convert the text to outlines.  Select the text object, and do *Object > Expand*

Comment: ... or `Type > Create Outlines` -- Your steps seem viable, although I don't think you need *actual* 3D, just offset duplicate shapes.